# Bash - increment a counter in a while loop if something is true

Tags: bash, loops

I want to increment a counter in a while loop, and once that loop is complete, echo out the counter. The $COUNTER should only increment if `$DATE >= $SINCE`

```
   last -f /var/log/btmp |
while read line; do
    set -- $line
    [[ $1 == "$CURRENTUSER" ]] || continue
    [[ $(date -d "$4 $5 $6 $7" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) -ge $SINCE ]] && echo "FAILED LOGIN $line" && ((COUNTER+=1))
    echo $COUNTER //echos 1, 2 etc
done

echo "Top counter:"$COUNTER //echos 0
```

Comment: Tagged as bash, so the next approach is not suitable as an answer:
Start your script with #!/bin/ksh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was one of scope. Piping into the while means the $COUNTER goes out of scope. A good explanation is http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Solution was from Chris's comment on this post:

http://www.edwardawebb.com/linux/scope-issue-bash-loops[enter link description here](http://www.edwardawebb.com/linux/scope-issue-bash-loops)

```
COUNTER=0

STDOUT=$(last -f /var/log/btmp)

        while read line; do
            set -- $line
            [[ $1 == "$CURRENTUSER" ]] || continue
            [[ $(date -d "$4 $5 $6 $7" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) -ge $SINCE ]] && echo "FAILED LOGIN $line" && ((COUNTER+=1))
        done <<EOF

        $STDOUT
        EOF

        echo "counter:$COUNTER"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with this line:

```
[[ $(date -d "$4 $5 $6 $7" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) -ge $since ]] && echo "$line && COUNTER=$[$COUNTER +1]"
```

You will want something like:

```
[[ $(date -d "$4 $5 $6 $7" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) -ge $since ]] && echo "$line" && ((COUNTER+=1))
```

If you want to display and increment, then:

```
[[ $(date -d "$4 $5 $6 $7" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) -ge $since ]] && echo "$line $((COUNTER+=1))"
```

Comment: That works for my echo in the while loop, but the echo of $COUNTER afterwards still prints 0

Comment: Hmm. that's strange. I tested here and it works fine: `( COUNTER=0; line="dog"; for i in $(seq 1 3); do echo "$line $((COUNTER+=1))"; done; echo "COUNTER $COUNTER" )` output is: `dog 1  dog 2  dog 3  COUNTER 3`

Comment: @Kiksy Where is the input for your while loop? You should have something line `done < file_to_read.txt` Also, you don't really have the `//` for comments in the file do you? That is not a valid bash comment. Use `#` instead.

Comment: Try: `echo "Top counter: $COUNTER"` and get rid of the `//` change to `#` for comments.

Comment: outputs 2,2,2,2,2 TOPCOUNTER:0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57899/discussion-between-david-c-rankin-and-kiksy).

Comment: How often are you getting new information in /var/log/btmp? How big is it? If you only have to check every minute or longer, then you can use cron to call your script rather than trying to pipe the output from last to the loop. Why not just do `last -f /var/log/btmp > tmp` and `while ... do ... done < tmp`

Answer (score 0):

Pipes commands are executed each in their own sub-shell. Variables modifications are confined in that sub-shell, and will not propagate back to the parent shell.

Using `bash`, a common workaround to avoid that pitfall is to use *process substitution* :

```
while read line; do
    set -- $line
    [[ $1 == "$CURRENTUSER" ]] || continue
    [[ $(date -d "$4 $5 $6 $7" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S) -ge $SINCE ]] && echo "FAILED LOGIN $line" && ((COUNTER+=1))
    echo $COUNTER //echos 1, 2 etc
done < <(last -f /var/log/btmp)
#    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```